# Display Homepage on 404 Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, server

I am trying to redirect a 404 request to the homepage of our website which is simply index.php. An example URL that is receiving a 404 error message is this URL https://www.website.com/directory/page. I tried adding the following line to my configuration file: `error_page 404 /index.php;`. When I did that, I no longer receive a 404 on **HTTPS** request. It displays the homepage as I hoped. But I am still getting a 404 error on **HTTP** requests. Any suggestions on how to get this to work on **HTTP** as well?

I am currently running an NGINX server. Here is my part of my configuration file:

```
server {
    server_name acme.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.acme.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.acme.com;

    #BEGIN SSL
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/acme.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/acme.com.key;

    # Makes for the most secure connections
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;
    #END SSL

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the response code in the `error_page` statement. To return the response code generated by the PHP script, use:

```
error_page 404 = /index.php;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) for details.

---

Alternatively, if the 404 response in question is being generated by your second `try_files` statement, add the `/index.php` there. For example:

```
try_files $uri /index.php =404;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried both of your solutions but unfortunately neither solved my issue. **index.php** is displayed when I visit this url **https**://www.website.com/directory/page. However, when I visit the same URL with just HTTP (**http**://www.website.com/directory/page) it does not display index.php, it just displays a blank white page. Any suggestions on how to get this to work on HTTP requests as well? Thanks.